# Minimizing a function using gradient (example from Wikipedia)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization

This example is from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient):

The gradient of function $f(x,y,z)=2x+3y^2-sin(z)$ is $\nabla f= 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} i +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} j +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} k = 2i+ 6yj -\cos(z)k$.

Ok, undertood. Taking partial derivatives. Now, if wanted to actually find the minima/maxima of that function using the gradient I just computed, what should I do? The wikipedia article does not tell me.

Btw: why do I need those i,j,k?

Answer (score 1):

You need the $i$, $j$, $k$ because the gradient is a vector, as it easy on the Wikipedia page. $i$, $j$ and $k$ are the unit vectors. Your gradient is actually:
$\nabla f(x,y,z) = \left(2, 6y, -cos(z)\right)^T$

Now, if the function is sufficiently "nice", (i.e. differentiable and so on), minima and maxima (except those at the border of the domain, but if you're in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you don't have a border) have to be at positions at which the gradient vanishes, i.e. all its components become zero.

However, in your case, the first component of the gradient is a constant $2$, therefore, the gradient vanishes nowhere and the function has no minima or maxima.

If you have a function whose gradient does vanish, you can then check if the point really is a minimum or a maximum, and which of the two, by looking at the definiteness of the Hesse matrix at this point. (positive definite means minimum, negative definite means maximum, indefinite means saddle point) However, this is only a *sufficient* criterion, not a *necessary* one. If the Hesse matrix is only semidefinite, this tells you nothing. This is similar to the second derivative of a function in one variable being $0$.